# How to make a bidirectional one-to-one relation by GreenDAO?

Tags: java, android, orm, greendao

I use ORM GreenDAO for DAL layer of my Android app. I've a problem in one to one relation between two tables. for example:

```
Entity page = schema.addEntity("Page");
Entity bookmark = schema.addEntity("Bookmark");

Property pageIdProperty = bookmark.addLongProperty("pageId").getProperty();

bookmark.addToOne(page, pageIdProperty); // any bookmark related to a page
page.addToOne(bookmark, pageIdProperty); // any page can has a bookmark
```

Is this relation mistake?

When I define it, I can't call `page.getBookmark()` in the **Page Class**

If this is true, Does any way I can make it bidirectional for one to one relationship?

Answer (score 5):

First off, good use cases for one-to-one relations are rare. Are you sure that it's not a one-to-many? If you still think it's a one-to-one: does it make sense to merge both entities into one?

Besides that, bookmark.addToOne(page, pageIdProperty) is fine, while page.addToOne(bookmark, pageIdProperty) does not work. To-one relations require the id property to be in the same entity. To-many would work this way, check the [documentation on relation](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/relations/) for details.

Comment: My personal reason for 1-to-1 is lazy loading. As I understand from your implementation, lazy is only supported on "Properties to (lists of) Entities". A concrete sample is: myCalendarEntity.getGoogleSyncData().getGoogleId()... I don't want to load the GoogleSyncData object, as I will only need it when I need to sync (which is not often)

Comment: I have a use-case where one side is a synced entity from the server (so its supposed to be readonly for the app logic) and the other side is local data and can be written by the app. +1 for bi-directional OneToOne-relations :)

Answer (score 1):

Best workaround so far is to use the addToOne on the entity where the foreign key exists and addToMany on the other side. It is not terribly inconvenient as you only have to make sure that you add one object to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors. First you need to create a PK before FK property on bookmark.

Try this:

```
Entity page = schema.addEntity("Page"); 
Entity bookmark = schema.addEntity("Bookmark");

bookmark.addLongProperty("bookmarkId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
Property fkPage = bookmark.addLongProperty("pageId").getProperty();

bookmark.addToOne(page, fkPage).setName("page");
```

Do the same steps for Page entity.